# How to invoke Method immediately after instantiating

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5

I have a controller that calls an api to get a list of Positions and Employees .  First it puts the api results into a model class - IDMSElements (1).  Then the controller takes the IDMSElements object and converts it to a PositionSlots object (2). Then the PositionSlots object needs to be updated with additional data from a database (3).  So in simplified version of my controller I have:

```
        (1) IDMSElements elements = getslots.CopyDocToElements(doc);
        (2) PositionSlots myslots = (PositionSlots)elements;         
        (3) myslots.UpdateDetails(db);
```

I am concerned about the myslots.UpdateDetails(db) because additional code in the controller depends on UpdateDetails having been run.  I would like the UpdateDetails to be run by default when creating the PositionSlots object. But I think multiple database calls in a constructor probably should not be done.  How can I make it so the UpdateDetails is automatically invoked after the PositionSlots object is instantiated?

Thank you very much!

Controller:

```
[Authorize]
public class PSListController : Controller
{
    private static readonly log4net.ILog _logger = log4net.LogManager.GetLogger(System.Reflection.MethodBase.GetCurrentMethod().DeclaringType);
    private PositionControlContext db = new PositionControlContext();
    private GetPositionSlots getslots = new GetPositionSlots();

    ...

    public async Task<ActionResult> ByCostCenter(int costCenter)
    {

        string ssapiuri = getslots.BuildAPIuri($"/current/?UDAKunit={costCenter.ToString()}");
        _logger.Debug($"{ssapiuri.ToString()}");


        Stopwatch stopWatch = new Stopwatch();
        stopWatch.Start();

        HttpResponseMessage result = await getslots.GetDataFromIDMSapi(ssapiuri);

        stopWatch.Stop();
        _logger.Debug($"Response received.  Milliseconds elapsed: {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()}");

        if (result.StatusCode != HttpStatusCode.OK)
        {
            _logger.Debug("Error retrieving data from API.  Milliseconds elapsed: " + stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString());
            throw new HttpException(404, "NotFound");
        }


        stopWatch.Restart();

        XDocument doc = XDocument.Load(result.Content.ReadAsStreamAsync().Result);

        stopWatch.Stop();
        _logger.Debug($"API result loaded into XDocument.  Milliseconds elapsed: {stopWatch.Elapsed.TotalMilliseconds.ToString()}\n");
        _logger.Debug(doc.ToString());


        IDMSElements elements = getslots.CopyDocToElements(doc);
        XMLDocStats docstats = new XMLDocStats(elements);
        _logger.Debug(docstats.ToString());

        PositionSlots myslots = (PositionSlots)elements;
        myslots.UpdateDetails(db);

        //because this is dependent upon UpdatePositionSlotId having been run
        //need to find a way to force UpdateDetails to run other than calling from Controller??
        var mainPositionSlots = myslots.PositionsCurrentAndActive;


        var budget = db.Database.SqlQuery<Budget>("GetBudgetForCostCenter @costCenter = {0}", costCenter);
        List<Budget> budgetRows = budget.ToList();

        JobClassGroups jobClassGroups = new JobClassGroups(mainPositionSlots, budgetRows);

        Department dept = db.Departments.AsNoTracking().Where(d => d.CostCenter == costCenter).SingleOrDefault();

        var model = new ByCostCenter_vm(dept, myslots, jobClassGroups);

        ViewBag.stats = docstats.ToString();

        return View("ByCostCenter", model);
    }

    protected override void Dispose(bool disposing)
    {
        if (disposing)
        {
            db.Dispose();
        }
        base.Dispose(disposing);
    }

}
```

IDMSElements Class:

```
public class IDMSElements
{
    //properties
    public ICollection<IDMSElementData> Elements { get; set; }


    //constructors
    public IDMSElements() { }
    public IDMSElements(ICollection<IDMSElementData> elList)
    {
        Elements = elList;
    }

    //methods
    public static explicit operator PositionSlots(IDMSElements obj)
    {
        //this is assuming we are looking at a list of elements
        //that contains the "current" positions

        Dictionary<string, PositionSlotDetail> positionSlots = new Dictionary<string, PositionSlotDetail>();

        var sorted = from element in obj.Elements
                     orderby element.positionNbr
                     select element;

        foreach (IDMSElementData el in sorted)
        {
            if (!positionSlots.ContainsKey(el.positionNbr))
            {
                PositionSlotDetail psd = new PositionSlotDetail
                {
                    CostCenter = Int32.Parse(el.UDAKunit),
                    CostCenter_7Char = el.UDAKunit,
                    PositionNumber = el.positionNbr,
                    PositionSlotId = 0,
                    JobClassId = el.jobClassCode.Replace("-", ""),
                    JobClassFullDisplayCd = string.Empty,
                    JobTitle = string.Empty,
                    SalaryGradeCd = string.Empty,
                    FTE_percent = el.FTEpercent / 100,

                    EmployeeId = el.employeeID,
                    EmployeeName = String.Empty,

                    PositionEffDate = el.positionEffDate,
                    PositionEffDateNext = el.positionEffDateNext,
                    PositionBeginDate = el.positionBeginDate,
                    PositionEndDate = el.positionEndDate,
                    DirectLeaderID = string.Empty,
                    DirectLeaderName = string.Empty,
                    DirectLeaderNetID = string.Empty,
                    FLSAstatusCode = el.FLSAstatusCode,
                    FLSAstatusDesc = el.FLSAstatusDesc,
                    EmploymentTypeCode = el.employmentTypeCode,
                    EmploymentTypeDesc = el.employmentTypeDesc,
                    IsOverloaded = false,
                };
                positionSlots[el.positionNbr] = psd;
            }
            Assignment newAssignment = new Assignment
            {
                PvID = el.employeeID,
                AssignBeginDate = el.assignBeginDate,
                AssignEndDate = el.assignEndDate,
                AssignEffDate = el.assignEffDate,
                AssignEffDateNext = el.assignEffDateNext,

            };

            PositionSlotDetail thePSD = positionSlots[el.positionNbr];
            thePSD.Assignments.Add(newAssignment);


            if (thePSD.Assignments.Any(assignment => Regex.IsMatch(assignment.PvID, @"^\d+$")))
            {
                thePSD.Status = "FILLED";
                if (thePSD.Assignments.Where(assignment => Regex.IsMatch(assignment.PvID, @"^\d+$")).Count() > 1)
                {
                    thePSD.IsOverloaded = true;
                }

            }
            else
            {
                thePSD.Status = "VACANT";
            }


        }

        var output = new PositionSlots(positionSlots.Values.ToList());
        return output;

    }
```

...
}

PositionSlots class:

```
public class PositionSlots
{
    //Constructor
    public PositionSlots(ICollection<PositionSlotDetail> pslist)
    {
        Positions = pslist;
    }

    //properites
    public ICollection<PositionSlotDetail> Positions { get; }

    private bool DetailsUpdated { get; set; } = false;

    public IEnumerable<PositionSlotDetail> PositionsCurrentAndActive
    {
        get
        {
            return from position in Positions
                   where position.PositionSlotId > 0 && position.PositionEndDate >= DateTime.Today
                   select position;

        }
    }

    public IEnumerable<PositionSlotDetail> PositionsNotFoundInPositionControl
    {
        get
        {
            return from position in Positions
                   where position.PositionSlotId == 0
                   select position;
        }
    }


    public IEnumerable<PositionSlotDetail> PositionsClosed
    {
        get
        {
            return from psd in Positions
                   where psd.PositionEndDate < DateTime.Today
                   && psd.PositionSlotId > 0
                   select psd;

        }
    }

    public decimal ActualFTETotal
    {
        get
        {
            return (from position in PositionsCurrentAndActive
                    from assignment in position.Assignments
                    where position.Assignments.Count() >= 1 && (!assignment.PvID.Equals("VACANT"))
                    select position.FTE_percent).Sum();


        }
    }

    public int FilledTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return PositionsCurrentAndActive.Where(x => x.Status == "FILLED").Count();
        }
    }

    public int VacantTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return PositionsCurrentAndActive.Where(x => x.Status == "VACANT").Count();
        }
    }

    public int OverloadedTotal
    {
        get
        {
            return PositionsCurrentAndActive.Where(x => x.IsOverloaded).Count();
        }
    }

    //methods


    public void UpdateDetails(PositionControlContext db)
    {
        if (!DetailsUpdated)
        {
            UpdateJobClassificationInfo(db);
            UpdateEmployeeName(db);
            UpdatePositionSlotId(db);  //if not found, PositionSlotId = 0
                                       //UpdateIsBudgeted(db);
            UpdateDirectLeader(db);
            DetailsUpdated = true;
        }
        else
        {
            return;
        }
    }

    private void UpdateJobClassificationInfo(PositionControlContext db)
    {
        string[] jobClassIds = (from x in Positions select x.JobClassId).Distinct().ToArray();

        var JobClassList = (from jc in db.JobClassifications where jobClassIds.Contains(jc.JobClassId) select jc).ToDictionary(jc => jc.JobClassId, jc => jc, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (PositionSlotDetail psd in Positions)
        {
            if (!string.IsNullOrWhiteSpace(psd.JobClassId) && !psd.JobClassId.Equals("MISSING"))
            {

                JobClassification jobClassification;
                if (JobClassList.TryGetValue(psd.JobClassId, out jobClassification))
                {
                    psd.JobClassFullDisplayCd = jobClassification.JobClassFullDisplayCd;
                    psd.JobTitle = jobClassification.JobTitle;
                    psd.SalaryGradeCd = jobClassification.SalaryGradeCd;


                }
                else
                {
                    psd.JobClassFullDisplayCd = ($"{psd.JobClassId} not found in view V_JobClassifications.");
                    psd.JobTitle = ($"{psd.JobClassId} not found in view V_JobClassifications.");
                    psd.SalaryGradeCd = "--";
                }

            }
            else
            {
                psd.JobClassFullDisplayCd = "MISSING";
                psd.JobTitle = "MISSING";

            }
        }
        return;
    }

    private void UpdateEmployeeName(PositionControlContext db)
    {

        string[] empIdsStr = (from position in Positions
                              from assignment in position.Assignments
                              where (!assignment.PvID.Equals("VACANT"))
                              select assignment.PvID).Distinct().ToArray();


        // Positions.SelectMany(x => x.Assignments).SelectMany(x => x.PvID).ToArray();

        //string[] empIdsStr = (from x in Positions where (!x.EmployeeId.Contains("VACANT")) select x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToArray();
        //int[] empIdsInt = Array.ConvertAll(empIdsStr, int.Parse);

        var EmployeeList = (from emp in db.IdAM_personLU where empIdsStr.Contains(emp.pvID) select emp).ToDictionary(emp => emp.pvID,
                 emp => emp.EmployeeFullName, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        EmployeeList["VACANT"] = "VACANT";

        foreach (PositionSlotDetail psd in Positions)
        {
            string empName;
            if (EmployeeList.TryGetValue(psd.EmployeeId, out empName))
            {
                psd.EmployeeName = empName;

            }
            else
            {
                psd.EmployeeName = ($"{psd.EmployeeId} not found in Employee table.");
            }


            foreach (Assignment emp in psd.Assignments)
            {
                string empName2;
                if (EmployeeList.TryGetValue(emp.PvID, out empName2))
                {
                    emp.EmpDisplayName = empName2;

                }
                else
                {
                    emp.EmpDisplayName = ($"{psd.EmployeeId} not found in Employee table.");
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }


    private void UpdateDirectLeader(PositionControlContext db)
    {
        string[] empIdsStr = (from x in Positions where (!x.EmployeeId.Contains("VACANT")) select x.EmployeeId).Distinct().ToArray();
        //int[] empIdsInt = Array.ConvertAll(empIdsStr, int.Parse);

        Dictionary<string, IdAM_arborLU> DirectLeader = new Dictionary<string, IdAM_arborLU>();

        var EmployeeDirectLeaderList = (from emp in db.IdAM_arborLU where empIdsStr.Contains(emp.emp_pvID) select emp).ToDictionary(emp => emp.emp_pvID,
                 emp => emp, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);



        foreach (PositionSlotDetail psd in Positions)
        {
            if (psd.EmployeeId != "VACANT")  //will just leave DirectLeaderId and DirectLeaderName as string.Empty
            {
                IdAM_arborLU supervisor;
                if (EmployeeDirectLeaderList.TryGetValue(psd.EmployeeId, out supervisor))
                {
                    psd.DirectLeaderName = supervisor.sup_name;
                    psd.DirectLeaderID = supervisor.sup_pvID;
                    psd.DirectLeaderNetID = supervisor.sup_netID;


                }
                else
                {
                    psd.DirectLeaderName = ($"{psd.EmployeeId} not found in Arbor table.");
                }
            }

            foreach (Assignment emp in psd.Assignments)
            {
                if (psd.EmployeeId != "VACANT")
                {
                    IdAM_arborLU supervisor2;
                    if (EmployeeDirectLeaderList.TryGetValue(psd.EmployeeId, out supervisor2))
                    {
                        emp.DirectLeaderName = supervisor2.sup_name;
                        emp.DirectLeaderID = supervisor2.sup_pvID;
                        emp.DirectLeaderNetID = supervisor2.sup_netID;

                    }
                    else
                    {
                        emp.DirectLeaderName = ($"{psd.EmployeeId} not found in Arbor table.");
                        emp.DirectLeaderID = "--";
                        emp.DirectLeaderNetID = "--";
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        return;
    }

    private void UpdatePositionSlotId(PositionControlContext db)
    {
        string[] posnumber = (from x in Positions
                              select x.PositionNumber).ToArray();

        var slots = (from ps1 in db.PositionSlots
                     where posnumber.Contains(ps1.PositionNumber)
                     select ps1).ToDictionary(ps => ps.PositionNumber.Trim(), ps => ps.PositionSlotId, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (PositionSlotDetail psd in Positions)
        {

            int posSlotId = 0;
            if (slots.TryGetValue(psd.PositionNumber, out posSlotId))
            {
                psd.PositionSlotId = posSlotId;
            }
        }
        return;
    }

    private void UpdateIsBudgeted(PositionControlContext db)
    {
        string[] posnumber = (from x in Positions
                              select x.PositionNumber).ToArray();

        var slots = (from ps1 in db.PositionSlots
                     where posnumber.Contains(ps1.PositionNumber)
                     select ps1).ToDictionary(ps => ps.PositionNumber.Trim(), ps => ps.IsBudgeted, StringComparer.OrdinalIgnoreCase);

        foreach (PositionSlotDetail psd in Positions)
        {

            bool isbudgeted = false;
            if (slots.TryGetValue(psd.PositionNumber, out isbudgeted))
            {
                psd.IsBudgeted = isbudgeted;
            }
        }
        return;
    }


}
```

Comment: why not a method `IDMSElement.ToPositionSlot(db)` then `PositionSlots myslots = elements.Select(x => x.ToPositionSlot(db))`

Comment: I would say PositionSlots has too many responsibilities. Perhaps create another object that contains PositionSlots and the additional details. If this object does not exist, apparently the update has not been done.

Comment: Thank you, @tschmit007! If you would like to write your comment up as an answer, I will mark that as the answer.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can achieve this by writing a method:

```
IDMSElement.ToPositionSlot(db)
```

and then use it as follow:

```
PositionSlots myslots = elements.Select(x => x.ToPositionSlot(db))
```